# Creating Legends for QGIS 2.0 Feature Blend Mode Outputs

Tags: qgis, cartography

I am working on visualizing ~4100 buffered point features. The shading of the buffers is keyed to a field in the data. Because the buffers overlap, I turned on multiply in the new feature blend mode options. I like the visual result, but what seems to be missing is an ability to generate a meaningful legend for the resulting image. Are there any workarounds for this? Is the only alternative to venture down the path of polygon intersects and symmetrical difference operations?

[image: buffered points with multiply feature blend mode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you understand the theory of the feature blending mode "multiply" you are able to create a legend by self-assigning the colors and the corresponding value. The formula for the "multiply" blending mode color is as follows:

(color value of r, g or b)^n/256^n-1  where n = number of overlapping layers.

Example: r = 165; n = 3; "multipy" blending mode r color = 165^3/256^2 = 68.5

See this pdf for more information on "Understanding RGB Blending Modes"
https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiOuZqbg7bWAhWL0hoKHVYfCLAQFgg0MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.leswalkling.com%2Ftexts%2Fblendingmodes.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE7PUTRkPXs3iKUKuDJHrTx5P4rIw

Comment: Hi @kalakaru, how to create this custom legend in the layout panel of QGIS?